# Javascript Array to special Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

I need for an Plugin an Object structure like this:

```
{
    "Beer":145.53,
    "Apple (red)":7.33,
    "Apple (green)":0.03
}
```

Don't know how to write it that this shine.

I got the all values already so how to set it up like this?

Comment: Why use a plugin? Just learn JavaScript.

Comment: You need to expand on what you are wanting. Where does the Array come in? And what do you mean by special Object?

Comment: Also what do you mean by "shine"?

Answer (score 1):

Use this notation to make objects with those properties:

```
var obj = {};
obj["Beer"] = 145;
obj["Apple (red)"] = 7.5;
....
```